# C# WebRequest Keep-Alive with changing data

Tags: c#, ssl, webrequest

I am using a `WebRequest` to emulate a program sending data to a server. Looking at the request in Fiddler, I need to have an SSL-encrypted Keep-Alive connection that sends data every ten seconds, and this data changes with each request.

So, for example, the requests would look like this:

```
GET https://example.com/api?time=0&nextTime=10&id=10&session=213
GET https://example.com/api?time=10&nextTime=20&id=10&session=213
GET https://example.com/api?time=20&nextTime=30&id=10&session=213
```

I think I just don't understand the concept of Keep-Alive in this case, but regardless, `WebRequest.Create(url)` instantiates a request with the url, which is read-only, so it can't be changed later.

Because of this, to send the next request, I would need to create a whole new WebRequest for it, and it wouldn't be using the previous connection, defeating the whole purpose.

I need it to keep the SSL connection open while it sends this data. Are there alternative ways to do this? Am I just approaching it wrong/not understanding how this concept works?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Forget all of it.  You want to send request to some site and get some result from it but as it seems, you can't do it. Ask what your **real** problem is. Maybe it is not related with *ssl* or *keep-alive*

Comment: I have outlined my problem: WebRequest needs to create a new instance every time one of the parameters changes because the request URI is read-only. Will this defeat the whole point of using keep-alive or will it still use the same connection despite using different objects?

Comment: You think you know something and ask about it. *goto first comment;*

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but I think you need to use "CookieContainer"..

Declare a new object of CookieContainer, use it for each new WebRequest.
It will use the previous Cookies..
If you faced a problem, You should use fiddler to compare webRequests from your application and from the real site that come from browser.